# Version compatibility with .NET serialization?

Tags: .net, serialization

What are the methods of implementing version compatibility with .NET serialization?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with BinaryFormatter (which is usually where this kicks) - don't; it isn't (IMO) suitable for storage - only for transport (and versioning is much less an issue here, as you probably control both ends of the pipe). Many other serializers of every variety are available; most of them cope *just fine* with versioning.

Personally, I would go for:

- xml: XmlSerializer (DataContractSerializer isn't as flexible in the output, but can handle graphs)
- json: JavaScriptSerializer
- binary: protobuf-net (I'm biased here)

With any of these, you should be fine between versions, adding members, renaming fields, etc.

Actually, I'd use the above 3 **even if** I was just transporting (not storing).

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer in a rather general way.

For controlling version discrepencies in Binary Serialization, please read the following MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.80).aspx

For XML Serialization I don't have an article, but MSDN goes into explaining the use of XML attributes to control serialization, these also help cope with version issues:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=VS.85).aspx

The `OnDeserializedAttribute` is also helpful in manually coping with versioning, you can default new values here that weren't set from the deserialization stream:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx